# File uploding failed when i was uploding the file on google-compute instance, now it's showing xyz.zip.csupload. Can i resume it or retry it?

Tags: file-upload, google-compute-engine

Instance operating system is ubuntu 16.04.
I was uploading using the instance `upload file` option.
File size was 2.24 GB.
I didn't find anything useful on internet.
Thanks

Comment: Please be advised, [we are not Google customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) so the amount of help we can provide is limited.

Answer (score 0):

The file "xyz.zip.ccsupload" is the file with the partial upload. Once the upload is complete, then the file will have the proper name. You cannot resume the upload from where it left off. If it fails, then you will have to attempt uploading the file again.

The reason why it failed is most likely due to the file size. Due to the size of the file, I would suggest using the "gcloud compute scp" command to upload the file to the VM instance as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#linux).

Comment: Thank you i will do so.